# ICU 58 undefined reference in MSYS2/MinGW64

Tags: icu, mingw-w64

Using instructions from
[Compiling-ICU-with-MinGW](https://wiki.qt.io/Compiling-ICU-with-MinGW)
I got the following error

```
digitlst.o:digitlst.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `_free_locale'
digitlst.o:digitlst.cpp:(.text+0x8fe): undefined reference to `_create_locale'
digitlst.o:digitlst.cpp:(.text+0xa20): undefined reference to `_create_locale'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My build environment:

- MSYS2 with gcc version 6.3.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)
- 64 Bit Toolchain: pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
- ICU 58.2 Sources [ICU4C](http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/58.2/icu4c-58_2-src.zip)

I did

```
unzip icu4c-58_2-src.zip
cd icu/source
./runConfigureICU MinGW prefix=$PWD/../dist
make
```

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Edit: Same is with 58.1, but 57.1 works fine.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It might be a bug in ICU 58 configure script, since MinGW-w64 never offered `_create_locale`/`_free_locale` (although they're defined in the headers, they don't exist in `msvcrt.dll`, which MinGW-w64 links against). Have you tried the mailing list?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to build QT 5.8 with the latest version of ICU and this issue popped up...

I was able to build icu4c-58_2 by linking against libmsvcr100.a using x86_64-6.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1

It appears that these functions are missing from the default libmsvcrt.a